# how to combine hashes in a list of hashes?

Tags: python, iterator

I have a list of hashes that look like the below:

```
   [{'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
  'country': 'AU',
  'impressions': 3000,
  'region': 'Cairns',
  'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)},
 {'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
  'country': 'AU',
  'count': 9000,
  'region': 'Cairns',
  'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)},
 {'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
  'country': 'AU',
  'count': 3000,
  'region': 'Cairns',
  'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 7, 0)}]
```

There are two hashes that need to be rolled up because all of the dimensions are same and I need to sum count.  So...how would I use a python groupby in itertools to accomplish this task?  Any other means?

```
   rolled_up = [{'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
  'count': 12000,
  'region': 'Cairns',
  'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)},
 {'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
  'country': 'AU',
  'count': 3000,
  'region': 'Cairns',
  'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 7, 0)}]
```

Comment: You have `impressions` and `count`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groupby would be ok if the items that need to be rolled together are consecutive. Otherwise you would need to sort them first. I think a `collections.Counter` will be better for you

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> C = Counter()
>>> L =     [{'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
...   'country': 'AU',
...   'count': 3000,            # <== changed this to "count"
...   'region': 'Cairns',
...   'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)},
...  {'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
...   'country': 'AU',
...   'count': 3000,
...   'region': 'Cairns',
...   'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)},
...  {'campaign_id': 'cid2504649263',
...   'country': 'AU',
...   'count': 3000,
...   'region': 'Cairns',
...   'utcdt': datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 7, 0)}]
>>> for item in L:                        # The ... represents the rest of the key
...     C[item['campaign_id'], item['country'], ...,  item['utcdt']] += item['count']
...
C
Counter({('cid2504649263', 'AU', datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 6, 0)): 6000, ('cid2504649263', 'AU', datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 4, 7, 0)): 3000})
```

Then transform the Counter back to your list format

Comment: I have to say...that is pretty awesome:)  Thanks

Comment: Ho do you make the code more dynamic? Whih if I dont have item['campaign_id'], item['country'] in one iteration?  and in the next only item['campaign_id'].  Now its hard coded given fixed keys.  THe keys can change.

Comment: @Tampa, you have to make a hashable key from your dict. For example  `tuple(i for i in item.items() if i[0] != 'count')`

Answer (score 0):

> There are two hashes that need to be rolled up because all of the
>   dimensions are same and I need to sum count.

If that's all you want, how about:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for i in hashes:
   d[i['campaign_id'],i['region']] += i['count']

for k in d:
    print k[0],d[k]
```